# how to use split() function to separate a some text from a string value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS. I got a requirement to select a particular text from a `scope value`.
My scope value is:

```
$scope.myLogMsg = '1111 order is placed by Sukumar Ms(User)'; //output: by Sukumar Ms(User)
```

My expected output is **by Sukumar Ms(User)**

i want to  skip "1111 order is placed" from the given sting and take "by Sukumar Ms(User)"

I had tried using javascript split method but hasn't worked. Any suggestions

Comment: provide the code  pls

Comment: I guess you might want firstly split with "by"  then add "by" to the second token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I have written code for your logic in JS. You can implement it in Angular.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "111 placed by nitesh rana";
    var result='';
    var res = str.split(" ");
    for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
    if(res[i]==="by"){
        do{
        result=result+' '+res[i];
        i++;
        }while(i<res.length);
    }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```